# SignalR Catching Exceptions

Tags: signalr

I have a simple login hub which clients may submit a username. The hub throws a exception if the username is already in use. On the client I am trying to handle the exception and read the message. However the message I am reading is 'One or more errors has occurred'.

```
try
{
    await Client.SignIn(user);
    UserName = SignInInput;                      
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ //One or more errors has occurred }
```

I asked this message on the SignalR github and I received the response:

> You need to unwrap the errors. We provide this functionality via the SignalRError object. Here's a sample of how you can unwrap an `Exception` e.
>
> ```
> using (var error = e.GetError())
> {
>     Console.Error.WriteLine(error);
> }
> ```
>
> In the future please ask questions on sites such as Stackoverflow or chat with us in http://jabbr.net/#/rooms/signalr.

Now I'm looking through my Object Browser and I can't seem to find any such method or class anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's an extension method, in [`SignalR.Client.ErrorExtensions`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/SignalR.Client/Infrastructure/ErrorExtensions.cs).

Comment: Has this been implemented for the .NET Win8 Client ?